# Does Adblock+ stop scripts called "tracker"?

Tags: javascript, adblock

It seems that my script for playing tracker music files ( .xm/.s3m/.it ) that I inadvertently named "tracker.js" only works if I disable Adblock+

If that's the case, are there any other keywords that should be avoided when naming files, to save tearing my hair out in future ?

Comment: Note that ad blockers usually don't block tracking by default. But many users of ad blocking software also enable additional tracking protection (e.g. [Adblock Plus' "Disable Tracking" feature](https://adblockplus.org/features#tracking) which uses [EasyPrivacy](https://easylist.to/#easyprivacy)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adblock Plus works by two mechanisms:

1) A filter list which includes specific rules for specific sites.

2) A set of generic filter rules which apply broadly to all sites.

It's the second one that can get you in trouble when naming page elements.

As a general rule, avoid all element names that include the word "ad": "`adbanner`", "`advert`", "`adarea`", etc. These have a high likelihood of being filtered by generic filters.

Many adblockers have their own set of rules these days, but EasyList is still the most widely used. You can check the generic names here:

https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt

You can also do a search for Adblock filters targeting specific elements on your site here:

https://blockadblock.com/search-adblock-filters.php

Comment: Funny story I ran into a problem yesterday regarding my script named "ad-strip.js" which was getting blocked by my client. It stopped behaving this way after I renamed it to cleanHamepage.js, as the script's goal was to remove ads from my homepage only(the other pages have ads relocated to a div, as I still want to appreciate my host for giving me free hosting).